# Half-rock- half-forest-gnome

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races, gnomes

I'd like a new character I'm building to have the stats and background of a forest gnome, but primarily the personality traits (curiosity, inventiveness) of a rock gnome.
Does this seem like a plausible result of the union of rock and forest gnome parents?
 Are they actually capable of producing offspring together?
Is this a thing that exists in 5e rules somewhere?
Are there tribes of forest/rock gnome crossbreeds?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Ask your DM

There isn't any official cross-over rock/forest gnome option, but it sounds like all you're doing is choosing Forest Gnome but building your personality similar to that of a Rock Gnome.

Ultimately, that's between you and your DM, but developing your own character's personality really shouldn't be a problem even if it's not your typical forest gnome.

### Individualism and personality

It is very important to note that the 'guidance' in personality given is just that. Every creature is an individual and they can have their own personalities. As long as your personality isn't creating problems for the table, then really anything should go and you should be able to roleplay your character how you'd like to.

Comment: Yeah, I guess ultimately the answer here is "DM's discretion".  Cheers

Comment: @intuited It is only because players and DMs should work together and whether or not this 'works' for the table is the important bit. But there really doesn't seem to be any red flag here. It's just personality.

Comment: I personally let a player do this sort of thing... and I did it myself in another campaign I was in as a half sun/half moon elf (she went by the moniker 'Eclypse'). For my players I just make them choose which stat block they use, the rest is just flavor in all honesty... in my worlds the culture in which  you grew up makes the difference since my races are much more divided and not cosmopolitan.